# Radion button unclickable / uncheckable due to jQuery script (slider)

Tags: jquery, radio-button, slider

I'm using a [jQuery slider script](http://old.nabble.com/show-hidden-div-on-click-td18455184s27240.html) to show and hide content. The script works perfectly but has one downside: **radio buttons inside the sliding div are unclickable / cannot be checked**.

If you hit the radio button of "Keuzerondjes" or "Selectievakjes", you'll see a div slides out - and that the radio button you just hit isn't checked. Does anyone have an idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Returning false prevents the radio button from being checked. Try removing your return false statements if that is not the wanted behaviour.

Comment: Works like a charm now. Thanks Simeon!